# Getting two DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn when first checkBox column is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a function called **bindExDateGrid** it returns all records in database that have the same name and barcode for an entered item.. the code of this function works correctly but when I check the dataGridView checkBoxColumn another checkBoxColumn appear!!
How can I solve this matter?
Codes for **bindExDateGrid** function are:

```
private void bindExDateGrid()
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select itmName,quant,exDate from inventory where itmBar='" + sBillItemBartxt.Text + "' and itmName='" + sBillItemNametxt.Text + "'", cn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    exDatedgv.DataSource = dt;      

    // Adding checkBox column to dataGridView
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    checkColumn.Name = "itmCheckedCol";
    checkColumn.HeaderText = "Selection";
    checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
    exDatedgv.Columns.Add(checkColumn);

    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Possible, that when you check checkbox you execute `bindExDateGrid` again.

Comment: @Fabio how do I stop the second execution of function?

Comment: Use SQL Parameters always; as for the question, you are apparently reusing that method which adds a column.  Split it up and call the add-a-check-column part only once

Comment: @Plutonix you mean parameterized query?

Comment: @Plutonix how do I can split the method calling from adding checkBoxColumn?

Comment: Why add a check box columns when simply adding a boolean column will do same.  dt.Columns.Add("Selection", typeof(Boolean));

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding columns to dataGridView by design not by using codes and now when I check the checkBox no more checkBoxes appear.